# Issue with DateTime::Locale::en_US module when upgrading

Tags: windows, perl, cpan

I have an issue with [`DateTime::Locale::en_US`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Locale::en_US) module.

I am running ActiveState Perl (64 bit) for Windows.

I am trying to upgrade from v5.16.3 to v5.22.2.

After installing the [`DateTime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) module and running my Perl scripts I am getting an error message:

> ```
> Can't locate DateTime/Locale/en_US.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DateTime::Locale::en_US module)
> ```

I am not able to install that module via ActiveState PPM.

I am able to install it via CPAN.

If I install it via CPAN, `DateTime::Locale::en_US` is downgraded from 1.05 to 0.92.

When I am trying to run the script after, it complains that 0.92 is incompatible and want me to upgrade back to 1.05.

Comment: your cpan config must be going to some out of date location. what does `o conf urllist` show?

Comment: urllist
0 [http://ppm.activestate.com/CPAN]
1 [http://cpan.perl.org]

Comment: within cpan try `reolad index` then `reload cpan`. Something is very wrong because the version numbers don't match those on the repos. Do you have more than one perl installed?

Comment: No luck. I even upgrade CPAN from 2.11 to 2.14. After trying to reinstall Datetime::Locale it still installs 0.92. I am running only one version of PERL

Comment: can you post a pastebin or update your Q with an install attempted from within the Shell? As a last resort manually download the correct .gz file from cpan and do it manually

Comment: I made it work by installing 1.26 version of DateTime. Thanks for you help Dr. A